# GAE blobstore upload fails with CSRF token missing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, blobstore, flask-wtforms

I'm running flask on app engine. I need to let users upload some files. For security reasons I have `csrf = CsrfProtect(app)` on the whole app, with specific url's exempted using the `@csrf.exempt` decorator in flask_wtf. (Better to implicitly deny than to implicitly allow.)

Getting an upload url from blobstore with `blobstore.create_upload_url` works fine, but the upload itself fails with a `400`; `CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

This problem is on the development server. I have not tested it on the real server, since it is in production.

How do I exempt the `/_ah/` path so the uploads work?

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use the approach outlined at http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html ...:

> You can also disable CSRF protection in all views by default, by
>   setting WTF_CSRF_CHECK_DEFAULT to False, and selectively call
>   csrf.protect() only when you need. This also enables you to do some
>   pre-processing on the requests before checking for the CSRF token:

The original example given at that page is:

```
@app.before_request
def check_csrf():
    if not is_oauth(request):
        csrf.protect()
```

but of course in your case you'd change it to:

```
@app.before_request
def check_csrf():
    if not request.path.startswith('/_ah/):
        csrf.protect()
```

Note that this is **still** default-deny -- every request demands CSRF protection... **except** those whose path starts with `/_ah/`, exactly as you require.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `AttributeError: 'CsrfProtect' object has no attribute 'protect'`. What is that 'csrf' variable supposed to be?

Comment: Apparently the protect method is on the master branch, but not on the latest version on PyPI, which is 0.11. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so the real problem was that I was giving an absolute url to the successpath  argument (i.e. the first) of `blobstore.create_upload_url()`, causing the request notifying about the success caused a csrf error when loading the root path (`/`). I changed it to a path relative to the root and now just using `@csrf.exempt` as normal works fine.